# How to temporary disable yassnipet snippet in snippet

Tags: yasnippet

I'm new to yassnipet and it's been awesome but I hit a wall.
I have the following snippet:

```
$1 = errors.WithMessage($1, $2))$0
```

In most of the use cases on `$1` I enter `err` which expands to another snippet.

I would like to temporary disable `yas-triggers-in-field` for this snippet only, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In most of the use cases on `$1` I enter `err` which expands to another snippet.

Then you might want to instead use

```
${1:err} = errors.WithMessage($1, $2))$0
```

That way you don't even have to type the `err` in, and since the cursor will be the beginning of the field, typing `TAB` will switch to the next one rather than expanding it.

---

> I would like to temporary disable `yas-triggers-in-field` for this snippet only, is there a way to do it?

Yes, add it to the [`expand-env` directive](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-2-5):

```
# name: errors-with-message
# key: emsg
# expand-env: ((yas-triggers-in-field nil))
# --
$1 = errors.WithMessage($1, $2))$0
```

Note that this requires a recent yasnippet which includes [this update](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/commit/4ee3835adf3352406aaa7dacc24f676f97b3cac2).  It's not included in 0.11 (the latest stable release as of this writing).